# Android App: Original UI is gone when an activity calls another

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, tabs

Currently I have a main activity that sets up 5 different tabs that correlate to 5 different activities.

One of these activities is a list activity. I wrote it so that when you click on one of these items, it launches another activity (WebActivity) with a URL string passed along inside the intent.

But the thing is when WebActivity is launched, the original 5 tabs are gone. How can I retain the original UI setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using ActivityGroup.

Here's an excellent tutorial: http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity